# HTML href link is opening two tabs for some reason. How can I stop this?

Tags: html

We have an specific program that displays a webpage we can write/edit. At many points on the page are images that, when clicked, are links to other webpages. We have the target="_blank" tag added so that it opens in a a separate web browser, rather than in the program. All of this works, and is fine.

Recently, I needed to add an image to the top of the page that takes the user to another web page. So, I copied the image and link that I know works, pasted it at the top, and changed the image, link, and dimensions to suit my needs. The problem is that now, it opens the link twice, each in its own tab. I can't figure out why it's doing this. I changed the link in question to google.com, and it behaved the same way, so I know it isn't the page we're linking to. I changed the image, and it behaves the same way, so I know it isn't that. I took away all of the extra features, deleted the css at the beginning, removed everything after the image, and it all makes the same thing happen. No matter what I do, what I change, it always opens two tabs. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening, and what I can do to stop it?

Here is the code I am using, after deleting all the Javascript and other features (still opens twice in two tabs):

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="The-Image-In-Question.jpg" width="100%" height="50%"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the content of href and set it to empty string. To determine if the value of href is  modified dynamically ?

Comment: It might have something to do with your script. Do you have a script handling click events ?

Comment: @VirtualTroll I'm not sure what you mean. If I remove the link, I wouldn't be able to click it anymore, right?

Comment: @IlSaggioVecchino There's Javascript at the top of the page, but I deleted it and it still does the same thing. So, I don't think that's it.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample code of both JS and HTML?

Comment: @IlSaggioVecchino I edited my original post, but there is no Javascript anymore. I delete all of it, and it still does that. Here is what I am using:<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="The-Image-In-Question.jpg" width="100%" height="50%"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have Javascript script that registered "onclick" for that tag and opens the tab as well and you also added target="_blank" to open it as well hence two tabs opened. Can you remove target attribute and see what happens?

Comment: Well, I deleted all of my Javascript and tried it again, and it still behaves the same way. Removing the target="_blank" attribute and trying it makes the page open in the original program, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really figure your problem, I think that we need to know browser you're working with, or is it an electron app. It's unclair. But, just try this as alternative to the `traget="_blank"`, it might work !

Don't try the snippet here, it might not work in reason of the way the script is handledunder the hood (It might not permit openning windows via the snippet), just copy and paste the code in your editor and try it out.

```js
document.querySelector('#myAnchor').addEventListener('click', function(){window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myAnchor"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200?text=Just+A+Placeholder+Image" width="100%" height="50%"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, running the code snippet didn't launch anything. It did act like a link, but clicking did nothing.

Comment: Don't run in the snippet, copy and past it in your editor please, and tell me if it worked

Comment: It's just displaying the image, and above it, the text "document.querySelector('#myAnchor').addEventListener('click', function(){window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')});"

Comment: Which browser are you using?!

Comment: Chrome, but it behaves that way in all browsers